# unable to get data save in database in fragment containing recyclerview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm working on integrating a database to save & contact information to be retrieved in fragment which contain the Recyclerview. The app is directly crashing when started.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.admin.navigationdrawer_demo, PID: 15637
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.navigationdrawer_demo/com.example.admin.navigationdrawer_demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
    at com.example.admin.navigationdrawer_demo.Person_DB_OpenHelper.getAllPerson_MYCONTACT(Person_DB_OpenHelper.java:149)
    at com.example.admin.navigationdrawer_demo.HomeFragment.fillListBirthdays(HomeFragment.java:64)
    at com.example.admin.navigationdrawer_demo.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:55)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
```

I am able to create the Database

DataBaseHelper.java:

```
public class Person_DB_OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String TAG="DATABASE";
    public static String DB_NAME="COMMUNITY_image.db";
    public static int DB_VERSION=1;
    public static String TABLE_NAME="PERSON_DETAIL_image";    

    public static String COL_ID="_id";
    private static final String COL_KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    public static String COL_FIRST_NAME="first_name";
    public static String COL_MIDDLE_NAME="middle_name";
    public static String COL_LAST_NAME="last_name";
    public static String COL_DOB_string="Date_Of_Birth_String";

    public static String COL_Date="Date";
    public static String COL_MONTH="Month";

    public static String COL_EMAIL_ID_MANDATORY="email_id_mandatory";
    public static String COL_EMAIL_ID="email_id";
    public static String COL_POSTAL_ADDRESS="postal_address";
    public static String COL_OFFICE_ADDRESS="office_address";
    public static String COL_MESSANGER_ADDRESS="messanger_address";    

    private String CREATE_TABLE= "create table "+TABLE_NAME+" (  "+
            COL_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+
            COL_KEY_IMAGE+" BLOB, "+
            COL_FIRST_NAME+" text, "+
            COL_MIDDLE_NAME+" text, "+
            COL_LAST_NAME+" text, "+
            COL_DOB_string+" text, "+
            COL_Date+" long, "+
            COL_MONTH+" long, "+
            COL_EMAIL_ID+" text, "+
            COL_POSTAL_ADDRESS+" text, "+
            COL_OFFICE_ADDRESS+" text, "+
            COL_MESSANGER_ADDRESS+" text);";   

        public Person_DB_OpenHelper(Context context) {    
            super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("Create","Table");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);    
    }    

    public long insertPerson(Person person)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL_KEY_IMAGE,person.get_image());
        contentValues.put(COL_FIRST_NAME,person.getFirst_name());
        contentValues.put(COL_MIDDLE_NAME,person.getMiddle_name());
        contentValues.put(COL_LAST_NAME,person.getLast_name());
        contentValues.put(COL_DOB_string,person.getDOB());

        contentValues.put(COL_Date,person.getDate1());
        contentValues.put(COL_MONTH,person.getMonth());
        contentValues.put(COL_Year,person.getYear());

        contentValues.put(COL_DOA,person.getDOA());    
        contentValues.put(COL_MEMBER_TYPE,person.getMember_type());
        contentValues.put(COL_PHONE_MANDATORY,person.getPhone_mandatory());
        contentValues.put(COL_PHONE,person.getPhone());
        contentValues.put(COL_LAND_LINE_NUMBER,person.getLand_line_number());
        contentValues.put(COL_EMAIL_ID_MANDATORY,person.getEmail_id_mandatory());
        contentValues.put(COL_EMAIL_ID,person.getEmail_id());
        contentValues.put(COL_POSTAL_ADDRESS,person.getPostal_address());
        contentValues.put(COL_OFFICE_ADDRESS,person.getOffice_address());
        contentValues.put(COL_MESSANGER_ADDRESS,person.getMessanger_address());
        Log.d("Object:","Person"+person);    

        long inserted_record_row_id=database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        return inserted_record_row_id;    
    }

   // public Cursor getAllPerson_MYCONTACT()
    public List<Person> getAllPerson_MYCONTACT()
    {
        List <Person> ListMyContacts=new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase database=getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor_all_record=database.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{COL_ID,COL_FIRST_NAME,COL_MIDDLE_NAME,COL_LAST_NAME,COL_PHONE_MANDATORY},null,null,null,null,null);
      //Cursor cursor_all_record=database.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{COL_MIDDLE_NAME},null,null,null,null,null,null);
        Log.d(TAG,"Cursor  "+cursor_all_record.getCount());
        while (cursor_all_record.moveToNext())
        {
            Person p=new Person();

            String name=cursor_all_record.getString(1);
            p.setFirst_name(name);

          //  Log.d("DATABASE", "NAME:- "+name);
            ListMyContacts.add(p);
        }
        //return cursor_all_record;
            return ListMyContacts;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
```

HomeFragment.java:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment    
{
    private Context context;
   // Context context=getContext();
    Person_DB_OpenHelper person_db_openHelper=new Person_DB_OpenHelper(context);
  //  Event_DB_OpenHelper event_db_openHelper=new Event_DB_OpenHelper(context);
    private List<Person> birthdays=new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Event> events=new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Person> aniversaries=new ArrayList<>();

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance()
    {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        //Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        fillListEvents();
        fillListBirthdays();
        fillListAniversaries();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
       recyclerView.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(birthdays,aniversaries,events));
        return view;
    }

    private void fillListBirthdays() {
        birthdays=person_db_openHelper.getAllPerson_MYCONTACT();
       /* Birthday birthday;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            birthday = new Birthday("birthday " + (i + 1));
            birthdays.add(birthday);
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: just stack trace cannot be used to recognize the problem, include your code in question too.

Comment: I am missing the onOpen() method in your `Person_DB_OpenHelper`

Comment: I got it, i am taking the view of the fragment